# Convert the syntax of razor @ to ASPX <%: %>

Tags: .net, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to know whether the Razor and ASPX syntax are both correct

Razor:

```
columns.Template(@<text>@Html.ActionLink("Create Facility", "Facility")</text>)
```

Web Forms:

```
columns.Template(<%: <text><%:Html.ActionLink("Create Facility", "Facility") %> </text> %>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Razor code seems fine:

```
columns.Template(@<text>@Html.ActionLink("Create Facility", "Facility")</text>)
```

WebForms needs a little more spaghetti code:

```
columns.Template(c => { %> <%= Html.ActionLink("Create Facility", "Facility") %> <% })
```

Comment: I am using Kendo Grid for ASP MVC4