# Invalid expression term ')' is shown in kendoUI for ASPX ASP MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Invalid expression term ')'  is shown in kendoUI for ASPX ASP MVC4

code:

```
     <%: Html.Kendo().Grid(gridobj)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.TMovie_id).Groupable(false).Title("ID");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("Name");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Genre).Title("Genre");
        columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Edit").Click("Editfunction"));
        columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Delete").Click("Deletefunction"));
        columns.Template(c => { %> <%= Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditMovie","Movies") %> <% });        

    })
    .Groupable()
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("", ""))

    )

%>
```

Compilation Error:
    Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'

       Source Error:


    Line 118:        columns.Command(command =>     command.Custom("Edit").Click("Editfunction"));
    Line 119:        columns.Command(command =>    command.Custom("Delete").Click("Deletefunction"));
    Line 120:        columns.Template(c => { %> <%= Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditMovie","Movies") %> <% });        
    Line 121:        
    Line 122:    })
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert the syntax of razor @ to ASPX <%: %>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394151/convert-the-syntax-of-razor-to-aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error.
If you remove ":" from <%: Html.Kendo().Grid , your problem will be solved.

Answer (score -1):

i guess you have an additional `)` in your code

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("", ""))
-----------------------------------------^
    )
```

<s>on a side note i think there is no need to close the `%>` before using the helper this should work</s>

```
<%: Html.Kendo().Grid(gridobj)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.TMovie_id).Groupable(false).Title("ID");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("Name");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Genre).Title("Genre");
        columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Edit").Click("Editfunction"));
        columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Delete").Click("Deletefunction"));
        columns.Template(c => { Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditMovie","Movies")  });        
    })
    .Groupable()
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("", "")

    )

%>
```

Comment: i used your code dakait but it is not coming it is showing me the same error

Comment: ok, when the view is rendered, look in the firebug console, are there any errors?

Comment: Ok dakait will get back to you once i get that